# Image morphing by integrating OpenCV2.framework in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, opencv, morphing

I am new to iOS and I am planning to work on my first app in which I have to morph one image into another smoothly. I have downloaded OpenCv2.framework and I am planning to integrate into my code. I have gone through some links showing the mathematical calculations required in this but I couldn't get it. Can anyone please suggest me some way or some sample tutorial demonstrating that how can we integrate and use OpenCv2.framework to morph one image into another in ios?  Thanks.